# Can Visual Studio Database Projects create individual diff scripts for each object that has changed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I'm beginning to work with Database Projects in Visual Studio 2010, and I know that it will generate a script that will deploy all of the changes (e.g., adding tables to columns, new ALTER PROC statements, etc.).

Can the Database Project be configured so that I would get separate files for each object?  For example, if three tables ad columns added, could I get one SQL file for each table contianing the ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN statement for that specific table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the answer is going to be "no" for this one. DB and SQL Projects are really designed to look at the state of your project, compare it to the state of your database, and make them the same in one pass. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in this case. Can you provide more details on why you need or want to generate separate ALTER scripts for every object that was changed?

Comment: If my database upgrade fails for some reason, I'd like to be able to easily know which update failed.  If I had individual scripts for each object, I could execute them one at a time and fail out if one of the updates didn't work.

Comment: Well, you do have the various "Print" statements in the publish script that tell you in what area the script is currently working. That may help pinpoint the problems. You'd need to capture the output of the script or check the output if you're running it manually.  I'd also make sure you're running the whole thing in a transaction if that's possible. That will allow the entire set of changes to roll back if there's an error in the normal schema change push. It doesn't help for Pre/Post Deploy scripts, but you can add some tracking there to help if needed.